# Updating multiple field in same table with different WHERE condition

Tags: sql, join, mysqli, sql-update

I ask myself if it is possible to update 2 field in 1 table but using 2 different where conditions. let me explain it. currently i am using 2 query like this:

```
UPDATE members SET last_game = $time WHERE userid = 1

UPDATE members SET game_played = game_played + 1 WHERE userid > 0
```

i wonder if there is a way to join these 2 query in sql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE members 
SET 
   last_game = CASE WHEN userid = 1 THEN $time ELSE last_game END,
   game_played = game_played + 1 
WHERE userid > 0
```

Comment: `1` is **always** greater than `0`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos But it's way slower than the original query