# How to UPDATE one field of my table with different WHERE conditions in ACCESS (In a SINGLE query)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the two following UPDATE Request :

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Sector = 'NameSector'
WHERE Sector IN('') AND ThType IN ('Test2')

UPDATE TableName
SET Sector = 'NameSector1'
WHERE Sector IN('') AND ThType IN ('Test1');
```

How can I Merge it ?

**Note :** [This Answer does not work on ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35356218/11167163)

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE (Sector IN(' ') AMD ThType IN('Test1')) OR (Sector IN(' ') AMD ThType IN('Test2'))`

Comment: @sagi Because depending on the `WHERE`, the value isn't the same, It would work if they where the same. I did a typo in Example, Its now Edited, Please have a look.

Comment: See if my answer works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `IIf`

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Sector = IIF(Sector IN(' ') AND ThType IN('Test1'), 'NameSector', 'NameSector1')
WHERE (Sector IN(' ') AND ThType IN('Test1')) OR (Sector IN(' ') AND ThType IN('Test2'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since  @[forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpas) answered at the same time with a shorter code I will accept his one. Thank you and I `upvoted` your correct answer since I can't accept both.

Comment: @Dorian What ever suits you, you should know that both queries do not neccesarily has the same functionality, if each of the `WHERE` conditions has different values inside the `Sector IN(' ')`, then @forpas query will update wrong records.. It does work the same though if its a single value or if all values are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Access does not support `CASE` expressions but you can use the function `IIF()`:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Sector = IIF('NameSector1' = 'Test1', 'NameSector1', 'NameSector')
WHERE Sector IN('') AND ThType IN ('Test1', 'Test2');
```

Comment: Thank you for you high quality answer. Your `SQL` is shorter than @[sagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5353753/sagi) and do the same. So for me your answer is the best one.

Comment: @Dorian Also `Sector IN('')` can be simplified to `Sector = ''`, but I left it as it is just in case you want to include more values in the IN list.

Comment: If there are multiple values in the `IN` list and they are not the same in both original `WHERE` clauses, then you will update records that were not meant to be updated..

Comment: @Dorian The condition Sector IN('') is common in both cases as you have it in your question so there is no need to make the code so complex.